# Java Linked Lists insert method without duplicates?

Tags: java, linked-list, duplicates

I couldn't find the right method for doubly linked lists insert. I want to do add elements in linked lists but without duplicate permission. If I write a new method for insert method, I can do it but I also don't want to write a new method, just need to find correct **if** condition.
My code looks like this:

```
public void insert(int newNumb) 
{
    DoubleLink newLink = new DoubleLink(newNumb);
    DoubleLink previous = null;
    DoubleLink current = first;

    while(current != null && newNumb> current.number)
    { 
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
    }
    if(previous==null) 
        first = newLink; 
    else 
        previous.next = newLink; 
    newLink.next = current;
}
```

Comment: Are you creating a new class or do you want to use the Java class `LinkedList`?

Comment: I'd change the loop second condition to `newNumb>= current.number` and after the loop add check if `newNumb == current.number` - if true, do nothing or handle duplicate in some other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void insert(int newNumb) 
{
    DoubleLink newLink = new DoubleLink(newNumb);
    DoubleLink previous = null;
    DoubleLink current = first;

    while(current != null && newNumb >= current.number)
    { 
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
    }
    if(previous == null) 
        first = newLink; 
    else {
        if(previous.number == newNumb) // newNumb is already in the list
            return; // do nothing
        previous.next = newLink; 
    }         
    newLink.next = current;
}
```

Comment: No worries. Welcome to Stack Overflow community : )

Comment: Assuming you want your method return true when newNumb is inserted, otherwise false: 1) change the return I've added to `return false` 2) add a return in the last line `return true`